# How to configure Kafka streaming security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We use `spring boot` in our project.
It is required to configure secured spring cloud streaming with kafka.
Security connection should be managed using `keystore.jks` and `truststore.jks`
I tried to find some documentation how to configure `ssl` concepts.
No required information in official [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html). I've detected some information at [kafka site](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_ssl.key.password) but I do not know how to connect it with `spring cloud streaming`.
Forum answers that I detected don't work for me.
Anyway I think that I need to combine somehow

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
```

and

```
    security:
      protocol: SSL
    ssl:
      key-store-location: ${KEY_STORE_LOCATION}
      key-store-password: ${KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}
      key-store-type: JKS
      key-password: ${KEY_PASSWORD}
      trust-store-location: ${TRUST_STORE_LOCATION}
      trust-store-password: ${TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD}
      trust-store-type: JKS
```

is there any recommendations or required documentation links?

### P.S.

My demo application using kafka streaming works correctly in case topic is not secured?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input-channel:
          destination: input_topic
        output-channel:
          destination: output_topic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration`
>
> Key/Value map of client properties (both producers and consumer) passed to all clients created by the binder

So

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream: 
      kafka.binder:
        configuration:
          [ssl.security.protocol]: SSL
          [ssl.keystore.location]: /example/key.jks
```

You'd use dots for the Kafka properties, not dashes... Spring-kafka uses dashes for Boot auto config, not Spring Cloud